# How to swap DIVS using a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to find a way to swap (toggle) the showing of a div when a checkbox is checked and return to the original div when the checkbox is unchecked.

JQuery toggle seemed to be perfect for this but has now been depreciated. So I suspect a pure javascript approach may be best/easiest.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Thanks,

Rick

```
<input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="checkbox">Show Hidden Div ?</p>
<div id="layerOne">This DIV is shown by default and hidden when the checkbox is checked</div>
<div id="layerTwo">This DIV is hidden by default and shown when the Checkbox is checked</div>
```

Comment: @putvande http://forum.jquery.com/topic/beginner-function-toggle-deprecated-what-to-use-instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/RxqHq/)***

Just use a click handler and a toggle

```
$("#layerTwo").hide();
$("input[name=checkbox]").click(function(){
 $("#layerOne, #layerTwo").toggle();
});
```

Note: The [**event handler** for toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) is deprecated, not the [version which simply swaps visibility](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Answer (score 0):

**Pure javascript approach**

***javascript***

```
 var button = document.getElementById('toggle'),
        text = document.getElementById('text');

    button.onclick = function() {
      var isHidden = text.style.display == 'none';
      text.style.display = isHidden ? 'block' : 'none';
    };
```

***html***

```
 <button id="toggle">Toggle</button>
  <div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/emikux/320/edit)